# HTTP upload progress

Tags: c#, .net

I'm uploading some form data, including files, to a web server and need to track the upload progress. I do it by copying my upload data to the request stream of `HttpWebRequest` bit by bit and update the progress bar according to the number of bytes copied and the total number of bytes. According to another website, this will buffer everything and the actual network transmission takes a lot longer after that. I should set `request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;` to prevent that buffering. Unfortunatley, when I do that, the `request.GetResponse()` method blocks forever.

Here's some sample code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + multipartBoundary;
Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
postStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = postStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    int percentage = (int) (postStream.Position * 100 / postStream.Length);
    backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(percentage);
}
reqStream.Close();
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
```

It all works fine when I don't set `AllowWriteStreamBuffering`. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was setting `AllowWriteStreamBuffering` too late. This works fine:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
request.SendChunked = true;
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
request.Method = "POST";
...
```

By setting `AllowWriteStreamBuffering` in advance, it also told me with an exception that I must set `SendChunked` or specify a content length (which I didn't have at hand now).